# Why doesn't the code works when request and response are swapped as parameters in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Why doesn't the function in app.get does not work when I swap req and res? Is it not possible to write res before req?

```
 const express = require("express");
    const app = express();
    app.get("/",function(req,res){
        
          res.send("Hello World");
        
          });

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The order of the arguments is fixed. When you swap them, i.e. `(res, req)`, the arguments remain the same, you just named them differently.

This means that the code you are using is actually trying to use the send method on the request parameter, which won't work.

Comment: Where can I find the code in which the actual parameters are defined?

Comment: Accidentally made an edit on the wrong post (yours), please disregard, @bouffelec...

Comment: @AyushNarang You should probably have a look at the documentation: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html
Althought it would not hurt to learn some Javascript basics first.

Answer (score 0):

You don't swap the actual values they represent, just the parameter names. So req is still res, and res is still req.

This means that the code you are using is actually trying to use the send method on the request parameter, which won't work.